# Android Webview XHR request new cookie not persisted

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-webview

I have a Xamarin.Forms 5.0 application (for both iOS and Android). I am not sure if this is a Xamarin issue or just Android. On iOS it is working fine.

In the app I use a webview to display single page webapplication. Inside that spa I have a login page with a "remember me" checkbox. When this is checked, the backend creates persistent cookie instead of a sessioncookie. The login is done with a XHR request to the backend.

Seems all working fine, but when the app is restarted, it doesn't know the cookie anymore and the user has to login again.
When I do a full reload of the page in the webview (after login), it looks like the cookie is persisted. After restarting the app, the user is logged in automatically, so the cookie is available.

So the problem seems to be that new cookies in the response of XHR requests are not persisted, while the response cookies of a normal page request are.

Anybody any ideas about this?

**Added some code**

I created a simple Xamarin.Forms project with an Android app.
Added this in the MainPage.xaml:

```
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="(Re)Load"></Button>
        <WebView x:Name="wv"
                 WidthRequest="1000" 
                 HeightRequest="1000"
            ></WebView>
    </StackLayout>
```

And in the codebehind:

```
        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            wv.Source = "https://---.---.nl/portal";
        }
```

This loads a SPA webapplication. Not much code to show.

Comment: Have you try to set the cookie of webview via `CookieManager`? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT The cookie is not set by spa or app. It is a reponse cookie from the server, returned by a XHR request. Works fine in browsers and also in iOS app.
But it looks like webview in android is not persisting cookies from XHR response (seems to be treated as session cookie). For normal full page requests, the cookie is persisted.

Comment: Could you provide your code for us? We could not guess the code only with your description.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I have created a new empty project to reproduce it. See my edit. Not much to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear, at least for me, when the WebView flushes the cookies and when not.
The simple solution for me was to flush the cookies everytime the onPause lifecycle event of the activity containing the webview is called. This occurs when another activity is started, or the user switches to another app or closes the app.

```
    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.Flush();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As i know, UWP and iOS would share their cookie containers automatically between the WebView and native http client, however Android does not.

The WebView could use CookieManager to handle cookies. If you want to share cookies between the two, you will have to manually process the information. You need to know the Uri of the domain for these cookies.

```
private void CopyCookies(HttpResponseMessage result, Uri uri)
{
foreach (var header in result.Headers)
    if (header.Key.ToLower() == "set-cookie")
        foreach (var value in header.Value)
             _cookieManager.SetCookie($"{uri.Scheme}://{uri.Host}", value);

foreach (var cookie in GetAllCookies(_cookieContainer))
    _cookieManager.SetCookie(cookie.Domain, cookie.ToString());
}

 public void ReverseCopyCookies(Uri uri)
{
var cookie = _cookieManager.GetCookie($"{uri.Scheme}://{uri.Host}");

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie))
    _cookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri($"{uri.Scheme}://{uri.Host}"), cookie);
}
```

Comment: But I don't use native http client. The problem is that persistant cookies (not session cookies) are not persisted always (I guess new cookies from XHR response). So when app is restarted, the cookies are gone.

Comment: Have you try to save the cookie and then reload when you restarted?

Comment: See my answer. Flushing the cookies at some point seems to solve the problem. No need to reload manually